# Looking for a stylized "d" symbol for "dimension"

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I frequently have to use `d` in math-mode to represent the dimension of vector spaces or manifolds in physics.  But then, I don't want this symbol to be the same as the one used for derivatives or differential operators.  So I'm looking for a new symbol to represent dimensions.  `D` is too big, `\delta` is too "cryptic" (and I use it for other things anyway).

Here's a small code as example, to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

The symbol $d$ is the spacetime dimension.  Usually : $d = 1, 2, 3, \dots, \infty$.  We have $\mathcal{M}^d$, or $\mathbb{R}^d$.  $dx$ is a differential.  Some prefer to write $\mathrm{d}x$ instead, which I don't like.  Spacetime signature is
    \begin{equation}
        \sigma_d = -\, 2, \qquad \text{when $d = 4$.}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So what symbol could I use instead of `d` and `D`?  Is there some other curvy d symbol?

Comment: You could try `\mathfrak d` of the amsfonts package.

Comment: First of all, this question is heavily opinion-based. Second, you should use whatever is considered the norm in the existing literature in your subject.  Your goal of not wanting to confuse the reader with multiple uses of “d” will very likely just cause even more confusion.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Most papers are using « d » or « D ». I wanted to use something similar, but a bit more fancy.  Maybe **\textsl{d}**.

Comment: If most papers are using just plain `d` or `D`, so should you.  Also when writing a paper about cosmology, you can expect your readers to be intelligent enough to derive from context whether `d` is a dimension or the differential operator and in the unlikely event of an ambiguity, you can just write a sentence to point out what is meant.

Comment: May be `\textcursive{d}` from `frcursive` package ?

Answer (score 5):

I sometimes use Euler or Computer Modern Upright Italic for upright math symbols distinct from operators.  Usually, though, that’s been constants in ISO style.

Other available math alphabets include `\mathsf`, `\mathtt`, `\mathcal` and `\mathfrak`.

#### Examples

Here is a sample that defines a new symbol `\dimension`, as the letter `d` in Computer Modern Upright Italic:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{iftex} % For \iftutex
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format the MWE for TeX.SX
\pagestyle{empty}

\iftutex
% LuaTeX or XeTeX
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}

  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \setmathfontface{\mathui}{CMU Serif Upright Italic} % Includes Greek.
\else
% PDFTeX or other legacy 8-bit TeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathui}{T1}{cmr}{m}{ui}
\fi

\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\dimension{\mathui{d}}

\begin{document}

The symbol \(\dimension\) is the spacetime dimension.  Usually :
 \(\dimension = 1, 2, 3, \dots, \infty\).  We have
 \(\mathcal{M}^{\dimension}\), or \(\mathbb{R}^{\dimension}\).  \(dx\) is
 a differential.  Some prefer to write \(\mathrm{d}x\) instead, which I don't
 like.  Spacetime signature is
    \begin{equation}
        \sigma_{\dimension} = -\, 2, \qquad \text{when\ } \dimension = 4.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern font sample]

And my go-to example for upright math symbols distinct from the operator font: Euler’s identity, with constants set in Hermann Zapf’s AMS Euler and text in (a clone of) his Palatino.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} % For \iftutex
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Format this MWE for TeX.SX
\pagestyle{empty}

\iftutex
  % LuaTeX or XeTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
  \setmathfont{Asana Math}
  \setmathfont{Neo Euler}[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                                 bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                                 cal,bfcal,frak,bffrak}]
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{tgpagella}
  \usepackage{newpxmath}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\symup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{euler}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"19}
\fi

\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos x + \upi \sin x \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler sample]

Comment: Could you give a specific example (from my code above), about how you would use Euler or other upright math symbols?

Comment: @Cham Okay, I added a pair of examples.